# Does a controller extend from a model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Been working on Rails for a bit I can't get my head wrapped around how there is almost nothing written in a model.rb file when just creating a basic CRUD application.

I was looking at a controller.rb file and was wondering why the controller file has access to model methods like all and create when there seems to be no connection between the two files.

Should't the model object methods like modelname.all and modelname.create etc. be written in the model file instead of the controller file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

No, it doesn't.

#### General Answer

A controller does not `have access` to model methods as you think, in the controller you never just write `all` or `create`, you write something like `User.all` or `@user.create`. You are calling the methods **on the model** class or instance. You are simply using the model in the controller, but this is not limited to the controller, you could do exactly the same thing in the views if you really wanted to, or you could create custom service objects, or policy objects, or repository objects, and you could still call `User.all` etc from inside them too.

For a very basic application you are correct you can get by writing very little or no logic, but this is only because Rails provides us with methods and does it all for us (hooray!).

Comment: Oh ok, so you can use the methods a model class has because you can actually call a model object in a controller and then call its methods...hmm

Comment: Yeah, so you create an instance of the model, like `@user = User.find(1)`. you then use that instance and call its methods, like `@user.destroy`. The same way you would with any class or instance.

Comment: Does the model.rb file get read when a model method is called? I would like to know the order in which the file gets read.

Comment: Rails autoloads all files in the app/ directory when the server / console is started. So all classes (models, controllers, any custom made classes etc) are already ready and waiting in memory to be called from anywhere.

Comment: I'm guessing there is an order to this and I would like to know whether the actual order would be that a model.rb would get read right after a controller action calls the model method. Or is the autoload thing something different than an order of files being read?

Comment: Yes the autoload is different, so files are not read in an order like you are asking, all the files are read and all classes loaded into memory when the server or console starts. What you are thinking about is the request cycle, which is: A request is sent, the routes file then directs the request to the correct controller and correct action, the logic you write in the action (for example @users = User.all) is then run, at the end of the action, the template is then rendered, or redirects to another action.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in a model file just means nothing *specific* to this particular model... inheriting from `ApplicationRecord` or `ActiveRecord::Base` means you have built in all the class methods (`all`, `where`, `find`, `find_by`, etc) and all the instance methods (`new`, `create`, `update_attributes`, etc) pre-defined for the model.

The controller determines what needs to happen, the model has the methods to make it happen, so

```
def index
  @model =  Model.all
end
```

Means that at the point of displaying a list of all model records, you access the model's class method `all`

Comment: So after the route.rb file is read and then the controller.rb file, does the model file get read when Model.all is used in the controller action?

Comment: Yes, the route directs to the correct model action, the model action will call class methods (`Model.all`) and instance methods (`@my_model.save`) as it needs to.   If you have something that needs to be done with several models you might build a "service"  that makes it one call for the controller.